# Why can't I reach this specific keybind through Python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to reach `view3d.view_qcd_slot` allegedly located inside `Object Mode` category. But I'm getting `KeyError: 'bpy_prop_collection[key]: key "view3d.view_qcd_slot" not found'`

###### Here's my train of thought:

I've got this code that works for `view3d.move` located inside `3D View` category.

```
wm = bpy.context.window_manager
wm.keyconfigs.default.keymaps['3D View'].keymap_items['view3d.move'].active = False
```

When I try it with my desired keybind, both `.keymaps['3D View'].keymap_items['view3d.view_qcd_slot']` as well as `.keymaps['Object Mode'].keymap_items['view3d.view_qcd_slot']` throw the `not found` error.

Inside the Preferences window it seems that `view3d.view_qcd_slot` is nested a little bit deeper, like so:
[image: illustration of how the two keybinds are nested inside preferences]

But when I exported my keybinds to a .py file to inspect it it seems they're right next to each other:
[image: illustration of keybinds in code form]

So I'm super confused why `.keymaps['Object Mode'].keymap_items['view3d.view_qcd_slot']` doesn't work. Maybe it has something to do with `keyconfigs.default`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The keymap item `view3d.view_qcd_slot` for the Collection Manager add-on can be access through:

```
km = wm.keyconfigs.addon.keymaps["Object Mode"]
kmi = km.keymap_items["view3d.discard_qcd_history"]
```

[Blender's Python API](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.KeyConfigurations.html#bpy.types.KeyConfigurations.addon) separates the access to the key configurations of add-ons from the default one. Hence `wm.keyconfigs.addon` has to be used.

Comment: Oh wow! I guess I confused it with the native system that hides (eye icon) collections with 1,2,3,4... keys, which Collection Manager does as well but with enabling/disabling checkboxes. But you're right! Now I see I can actually just disable the QCD hotkeys altogether in the addon's settings. Still, thank you very much!

Comment: The API page confuses me.  Should this entry also be available through the `wm.keyconfigs.user`?

Comment: @MartyFouts Yes, it is also available through `wm.keyconfigs.user`. I do not know the reason for this design decision either and would have to look it up.